# data type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

how to resolve this?

```
INSERT INTO logiciel VALUES ('log1','Oracle 6',13-05-1995,'6.2','UNIX','3000');
INSERT INTO logiciel VALUES ('log1','Oracle 6',13-05-1995,'6.2','UNIX','3000')
                                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwt8w.png)
here's the table
[the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OUFd.png)

```
 create table logiciel (
    nLog varchar2 (5) primary key,
    nomLog varchar (20) not null,
    dateAchat date,
    version varchar2 (7),
    typeLog varchar2 (9),
    prix number (6,2)
    );
```

Comment: [Datetime literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) in the Oracle manual

Comment: `13-05-1995` evaluates to `-1987`. That's a number not a date. The error message is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date literal or `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask. Do **not** insert strings into `date` datatype columns, hoping that Oracle will *guess* format you used.

```
SQL> -- date literal is always DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'
SQL> INSERT INTO logiciel (nlog, nomlog, dateachat, version, typelog, prix)
  2    VALUES ('log1', 'Oracle 6', date '1995-05-13', '6.2', 'UNIX', '3000');

1 row created.

SQL> -- TO_DATE lets you choose format, but then the format mask must follow it
SQL> INSERT INTO logiciel (nlog, nomlog, dateachat, version, typelog, prix)
  2    VALUES ('log2', 'Oracle 6', to_date('13-05-1995', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), '6.2', 'UNIX', '3000');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotes around your date value as dates are treated as string -

```
INSERT INTO logiciel VALUES ('log1','Oracle 6','13-05-1995','6.2','UNIX','3000');
```

But only using string will tell the DB to store it as string not as date. The difference between them is, You can not do any date manipulation on strings. So you have 2 option now.

1. Use To_Date function with date format -

```
INSERT INTO logiciel VALUES ('log1','Oracle 6',TO_DATE('13-05-1995', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'6.2','UNIX','3000');
```

2. Use DATE keyword which is supported by ANSI standard but with that, you have to use the date format as 'YYYY-MM-DD'-

```
INSERT INTO logiciel VALUES ('log1','Oracle 6',DATE '1995-05-13','6.2','UNIX','3000');
```

Comment: _"But only using string will tell the DB to store it as string not as date."_  No.  If the receiving column is defined as a DATE, then it will store it as a date. Period.  Full stop.  If all you give is a string ( a string that is a character _representation_ of a date), then you force oracle to perform an implied TO_DATE() function to get the required data taype.  And this implied TO_DATE will only work if the supplied string is in the same format as defined by the controlling setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.